# Populating the socket io sourced data into the html table

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax, sockets

I am trying to populate the html table based on socket io received data. I want to show the previous data aswell, and when I am adding row into specific user id table so I want to live update it. and show the data into html table. Below is my code. But it is only showing the data which is coming from socket , not showing the previous records. And whenever I add new data, it shows that data and removes the previous added data.

Here is the code I am using

```
 <div class="row"> 
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-header">
                                <h4 class="card-title">Invoice List</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="table-responsive">
                                <table id="results">
                                        
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
                
        $(document).ready(function(){
            
            function toTable( data ) {
  document.getElementById( 'results' ).innerHTML = "<tr><th>COIN</th><th>EXCHANGE</th><th>MARKET</th><th>PRICE</th></tr>";
  document.getElementById( 'results' ).innerHTML += "<tr><td>" + data.firstname + "</td><td>" + data.lastName.toUpperCase() +"</td></tr>";
}

            var socket = io('http://localhost:5001');
            
            socket.on('getinvoices', (data) => {
                console.log(data);

                toTable(data.doc);
            });
        });
   </script>
```

I tried the above code but its only adding the data and removing the previous data.

----JSON RESPONSE---

```
   {
    doc: {
      billingAddress: "House 130 Street ABC",
      city: "California",
      country: "United States",
      email: "john@gmail.com",
      firstname: "John",
      lastName: "doe",
      phone: "5418411247",
      state: "Oregon",
      zipCode: "97230",
      _id: "639b28528ae035dfcd5a4612"
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you add your data in json format to the question?

Comment: console.log(data);

Comment: wait I am updating the question

Comment: @DreamBold I've added the json response

Comment: Do I have to match the _id , to load previous data? Or do I have to make a seperate call to load the previous data first

Comment: I dont thinki it's a correct output, not a valid json data

Comment: it is valid json, and its already kinda working. but I have to load the previous data aswell and have to live update the new coming data into table aswell

Comment: https://codepen.io/dreambold/pen/gOjYBVr?editors=1111 It's not valid. Please have a look at this, do you need something like this?

Comment: I have edited the question with `VALID JSON`

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
document.getElementById( 'results' ).innerHTML = "<tr><th>COIN</th><th>EXCHANGE</th><th>MARKET</th><th>PRICE</th></tr>";
```

is resettng innerHTML of the table each time you call `toTable( data )`.
You should define your table header in your HTML file, and remove this line from `toTable( data )`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function toTable( data ) {
  document.getElementById( 'results' ).innerHTML = "<tr><th>COIN</th><th>EXCHANGE</th><th>MARKET</th><th>PRICE</th></tr>";
  document.getElementById( 'results' ).innerHTML += "<tr><td>" + data.firstname + "</td><td>" + data.lastName.toUpperCase() +"</td></tr>";
}
```

The problem is that you are resetting the innerHTML value when you use the `=` operator to assign it. You have two options:

1° Change the `=` assign operator for this `+=`

2° Send the old data in the socket too

The first solution works if you want to persist the old value only 1 time, but with this solution if you reload the page the table will shows only the actual value.

The second solution works if you want to persist the value until the next update happens, but you'll need to store the old value too.

I don't know what do you want exactly but these two solutions will work. The second solution assumes that you have other function to update the value without socket emission (in a normal page load request)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code. `DOMContentLoaded` event in JS is the same as `$(document).ready()` in jQuery

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  function addTableContent(data, whereTo) {
    var text = "<tr>";
    var results = document.getElementById("results");

    Object.keys(data).map((item, index) => {
      whereTo === "header"
        ? (text += "<th>" + item.toUpperCase() + "</th>")
        : (text += "<td>" + data[item] + "</td>");
    });
    whereTo === "header"
      ? (results.innerHTML = text + "</tr>")
      : (results.innerHTML += text + "</tr>");
  }

  var data = {
    doc: {
      billingAddress: "House 130 Street ABC",
      city: "California",
      country: "United States",
      email: "john@gmail.com",
      firstname: "John",
      lastName: "doe",
      phone: "5418411247",
      state: "Oregon",
      zipCode: "97230",
      _id: "639b28528ae035dfcd5a4612"
    }
  };
  addTableContent(data.doc, "header"); // This is to add the table header

  //Uncomment these lines so you can add the data from the Socket to the table body
  // var socket = io("http://localhost:5001");

  // socket.on("getinvoices", (data) => {
  // console.log(data);
  addTableContent(data.doc); //This is to append the data to the table
  // });
});
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        <h4 class="card-title">Invoice List</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table id="results">
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```